# Spark streamming task shutdown gracefully when kafka client send message asynchronously

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka

i am building a spark streamming application, read input message from kafka topic, transformation message and output the result message into another kafka topic. Now i am confused how to prevent data loss when application restart, including kafka read and output. Setting the spark configuration "spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdow" true can help?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Spark to do checkpoint to HDFS and store the Kafka offsets in Zookeeper (or Hbase, or configure elsewhere for fast, fault tolerant lookups)

Though, if you process some records and write the results before you're able to commit offsets, then you'll end up reprocessing those records on restart. It's claimed that Spark can do exactly once with Kafka, but that is a only with proper offset management, as far as I know, for example, Set enable.auto.commit to false in the Kafka priorities, then only commit after the you've processed **and** written the data to its destination

If you're just moving data between Kafka topics, Kafka Streams is the included Kafka library to do that, which doesn't require YARN or a cluster scheduler